# Plot mathematica get 'Invalid integration variable'

Tags: plotting

New to mathematica and trying to plot this function:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.24/x + 0.76/x^(-2)], x]
Plot[Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.24/x + 0.76/x^(-2)], x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But get error output:

```
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 0.000020428571428571424`.
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 0.02042859183673469`.
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 0.04083675510204081`.
General::stop: Further output of Integrate::ilim will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I'm not sure what the problem is in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Plot[Evaluate@Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.24/x + 0.76/x^(-2)], x], {x, 0, 1}]
```